# Wrapper class dynamic access to fields

Tags: wrapper-class, dynamic-binding

We have wrapper class:

```
public class Meta {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer total;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer count;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer offset;
    @AuraEnabled public String orderBy;
    @AuraEnabled public String orderDirection;

}
```

and I want to loop through all fields dynamically like:

```
for(String key: Meta.xxxkeySet()){
    String value = Meta[key or something];
}
```

I can add method like returnField(String fieldName) to the wrapper class, but I don't like that I would need to hardcode field names there and more importantly there are different variable types (in this example only Integer, String)(maybe use Object type here?). Did you have similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably Your looking for this .

```
public class MyClass {
public Integer attr1;
public String attr2;
public Decimal attr3;
}
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.attr1=1;
c.attr3=3.2;
c.attr2='hello';

String s = JSON.serialize(c);
Map<String,Object> obj =  (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
system.debug(obj.keyset());
for(string key:obj.keyset())
    system.debug(obj.get(key));
```

Convert instance of the object to jSon so that you get all field names. and Convert back to Map. So that you access it directly with keyset of Map dynamically .

Comment: @KarelL Your Welcome....